# Multi Dimensional Array in Shopify

Tags: ajax, collections, filtering, shopify, product

I am having an issue with building an Ajax product filter in shopify. I am wanting to do a sidebar that uses tags to sort products, but not reload the page.

Here is my code, and I am getting undefined for the 3 shopify calls to just try and get the products to populate on the page. I tweaked the api url at the end to allow me to select which collection based on the page I am on. What am I doing wrong here or is there a better way to do this?

```
/* Product Filter Ajax */
    var $products = $(".ajaxProducts");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/admin/api/2019-10/products.json?[ section.settings.collectionID ]',
        success: function (products) {
            $.each(products, function(i, product){
                $products.append('<li class="grid__item grid__item--collection-template small--one-half medium-up--one-quarter">' + product.featured_image + product.title + product.price + '</li>');
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you running this through your app or are you trying to run this on the frontend of your store? If the latter, you won't be able to use the admin API and will need to use the frontend endpoints like `/collections/<handle>/products.json` instead.

Comment: I created a snippet directly into the shopify theme itself. Is this what you are referring to?

url: '/admin/api/2019-10/products.json?[ section.settings.collectionID ]'

Comment: Aye, that - if you're putting your javascript into the theme via a snippet, you cannot use the admin API - at least, not without exposing admin credentials, which is a very bad idea!  Instead, use the frontend API endpoints